# iOS beta users and distribution users on same server with push notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing an iPhone app that uses push notifications.  I have a number of beta users successfully using the app (via HockeyApp), and these archives were signed using my development provisioning profile.  I only have one server, which is currently using the sandbox push notification certificates.  I'm about to submit my app to the app store, signed using a distribution certificate, and of course this comes with a production push notification certificate... if I switch my server to use this push certificate, won't push notifications stop working for my beta users?  Is there a way to have the beta users use the production push notification server?  I don't want my beta users to use a separate server because this is a social app and they need to be able to interact with non-beta users, so everyone needs to be on production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way for the app to identify itself to the server. You can use a compiler directive with different targets / build schemes to specify the app build type (beta or prod). Send the build type to the server along with the device token. You can then associate the build type with the device token for that user's device in your server-side database.

On the server, select the certificate to use based on the build type.

(of course, since you have beta's out in the wild already the absence of a build type also means beta:-)

Comment: That does appear to be the only way.  Thank you.  I just really don't like it, because there's no guarantee that the compiler directive actually matches the way the app is signed (someone could mess it up; we reprovision beta devices pretty frequently to add new beta users).  But, here's your accept and upvote for having a workable solution :D

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I understand how something could get messed up. I don't have experience reprovisioning repeatedly in the way you're talking about - maybe that's another question. But, I think there's a way to specify the code signing in the build settings for your beta in a way that you can set it and forget it.